# I'm creating attributes in Woocommerce, but they are not visible in the "Attributes" section

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a product in WooCommerce and attributes for it. Everything is fine, but I don't see the new attributes in the Attributes section.

```
function create_product() {
$product = new WC_Product_Simple();

$product->set_name( 'Название товара' );
$product->set_regular_price( '100' );

// Добавляем атрибуты "бренд" и "цвет" к товару
$attributes = array(
    'Бренд' => 'Ямаха',
    'Цвет' => 'Красный'
);
$wc_attributes = array();
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $attribute_value ) {
    $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
    $attribute->set_id( 0 );
    $attribute->set_name( $attribute_name );
    
    $attribute->set_options( array( $attribute_value ) );
    $attribute->set_visible( true );
    $attribute->set_variation( false );
    $wc_attributes[] = $attribute;

}
$product->set_attributes( $wc_attributes );
// Сохраняем новый товар
$product->save();

return $product->get_id();
}
```

I don't understand why this happens, I forgot something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **differences between product-specific and global attributes**. When you add attributes via code to a product, youre only adding them to the one specific product **(in your example)**. The attributes wont show in Woocommerce -> Attributes section. **They have to be added as global attributes.**

**heres the basic idea:**

1. Create the global attribute (if it doesn't already exist).
2. Get its taxonomy name.
3. Link it with your product.

This should work for your code example:

```
function create_product() {
    $product = new WC_Product_Simple();

    $product->set_name( 'Название товара' );
    $product->set_regular_price( '100' );

    $attributes = array(
        'Бренд' => 'Ямаха',
        'Цвет' => 'Красный'
    );

    $wc_attributes = array();
    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $attribute_value ) {
        // Check if global attribute exists
        $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $attribute_name );
        if ( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) {
            wc_create_attribute(
                array(
                    'name' => $attribute_name,
                    'slug' => wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name( $attribute_name ),
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'description' => '',
                    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                    'has_archives' => false
                )
            );
        }

        // Add the value to the global attribute
        $term = term_exists( $attribute_value, $taxonomy );
        if ( ! $term ) {
            wp_insert_term( $attribute_value, $taxonomy );
        }

        // Set the global attribute to the product
        $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
        $attribute->set_id( wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( $attribute_name ) );
        $attribute->set_name( $taxonomy );
        $attribute->set_options( array( $attribute_value ) );
        $attribute->set_visible( true );
        $attribute->set_variation( false );
        $wc_attributes[] = $attribute;
    }
    $product->set_attributes( $wc_attributes );
    $product->save();

    return $product->get_id();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Everything worked! Maybe it will be useful to someone else!